# Vue autocomplete in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, autocomplete

I'm working on an issue with a vue autocomplete function in a laravel site.

I've set my route, controller and blade. Currently, if I inspect the vue component and type in the input, it shows the keywords I'm typing in the console, so I know it's catching what I'm typing.

As for the $groupResult in my controller, if I just dump that on my page then it dumps about 100 results as expected. All I want to do is have an autocomplete on the input that searches within those 100 results.

What exactly am I missing here?

Route

```
Route::get('campaigns/categories','CampaignsController@searchcategories')->name('campaigns.categories');
```

Controller:

```
public function searchcategories(Request $request)
{
    $userNum = $this->user;
    $category = new categoryService();
    $safecategories = $category->info($userNum);

    $groupResult = array();

    foreach($safecategories->categories as $categories){
        $groupItem = array();
        $groupItem["group_code"] = $categories->group_code;
        $groupItem["group_name"] = $categories->group_name;

        array_push($groupResult, $groupItem);
    }

     return view('campaigns')
        ->with('groupResult', $groupResult);

}
```

Blade

```
<div id="categoryNames">
<input type="text" v-model="keywords">
<ul v-if="results.length > 0">
  <li v-for="result in results" :key="result.id" v-text="result.name"></li>
</ul>
</div>

var categoryNames = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      keywords: null,
      results: []
    };
  },

  watch: {
    keywords(after, before) {
      this.fetch();
    }
  },

  methods: {
    fetch() {
      axios.get('campaigns/categories', { params: { keywords: this.keywords } })
        .then(response => this.results = response.data)
        .catch(error => {});
    }
  }
}).$mount('#categoryNames');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply attempting to filter the existing results there is no need to call the server to do this.

```
<div id="categoryNames">
<input type="text" v-model="keywords">
<ul v-if="filteredResults.length > 0">
  <li v-for="result in filteredResults" :key="result.id" v-text="result.name"></li>
</ul>
</div>

var categoryNames = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      keywords: null,
      results: []
    };
  },

  computed: {
    filteredResults () {
      return this.keywords ? this.results.filter(row => row.name.search(new RegExp(`${this.keywords}`, 'i')) !== -1) : this.results
    }
  }
}).$mount('#categoryNames');
```

The computed property returns an array of objects (I assumed you are filtering on the object key name). If a keyword is present it uses regex to perform a case insensitive search. If keyword is not present it returns the full results object.

Note, I did not test this code directly so there may be a typo etc. But have implemented many versions of this in a large scale application.

Comment: So where exactly is this getting that function with groupResult then?

Comment: I imagine I would have to return the view with that function result, but then how do I actually filter that data?

Comment: Since this page is being rendered server side I would pass the groupResult to the view and bind it to the `results: []` results: {!! json_encode($groupResult) !!}. What I provided you is the filtering function

Comment: One item that is missing in your example code is when/where the Laravel view is being called. This would help round out this answer.

Comment: Sorry I should add that. It's just a returned view in an index function

Comment: Code? You should be able to bind the data to the view: view('YourViewName', $groupResult);

Comment: I have now done that, but should the 'result' that you have for :key and v-text be groupResult, as it is in my controller?

Comment: @TomN. the value for :key needs to be unique, If you have an auto incrementing ID that "may" be safe unless you joined another table into the results. In that case you can use the counter in the v-for like this: `<li v-for="(result, i) in filteredResults" :key="i" v-text="result.name"></li>` For the v-text simply use what ever key makes the most sense, I havent looked at the data so I made some assumptions based on your initial post. The important thing here is that the object key you use in v-text should match the object key in the filteredResults `row.name`